# Training with feature metadata - bayesian network (naive bayes)

Tags: machine-learning, python, naive-bayes-classifier, bayesian-networks

I am building a project for fun - reverse astrology!

I am making a dataset like:

```
planet_name, life_impact

Saturn, impact1

Saturn, impact2

Sun, impact2

Sun, impact3

Sun, impact4

Mars, impact 5

Mars, impact 6
```

etc…

I have trained a bayesian network over this^. I want the network to learn metadata based learnings also.

ie.
Right now for positive evidence “impact 1” network will contribute probability 1/2 to Saturn and 1/3 to Sun.

Now, I have metadata(duration) for feature: life_impact
duration for impact2 for Saturn is 1/5
duration for impact2 for Sun is 5/5

This should change the probability contribution to sun/saturn: Now contribution should change as per the value of duration also.
eg. 
impact 1 with duration 1 should contribute more to Saturn and less to Sun, similarly impact 1 with duration 4 or 5 should contribute more to Sun.

Note that metadata duration might not be there for all impacts, something else might be present like “relevance”

How should I design my features to accommodate this?